# Angular require parent controller with transclude not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the parent controller from the child directive and it is throw this error:

> Controller 'SelectHandlerController', required by directive
>   'inputControl', can't be found!

```
app.controller('SelectHandlerController', function() {  
  this.model = '';
});

app.directive('selectHandler', () => {

  return {
    controller: 'SelectHandlerController',
    controllerAs: 'shc',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    bindToController: true
  }


});


app.directive('inputControl', () => {


  return {
    template: `<div><input type="text"></div>`,
    require: '^SelectHandlerController',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'ic',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log(ctrl);
    }
  }

});

<select-handler>

  <input-control ></input-control> 

</select-handler>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `require` should be the name of the directive you're requiring. Not the controller.

```
app.directive('inputControl', function() {
  return {
    template: `<div><input type="text"></div>`,
    require: '^selectHandler',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'ic',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log(ctrl);
    }
  }
});
```